# What is meant by incompressible flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, differentiation, density, flow

What is meant by [incompressible flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow)?

1. The density of the fluid is a constant, $\rho = constant$
2. The density of a fluid has a spatial dependence but remains constant in time, $\rho = \rho(\mathbf{r})$

In both cases $\rho$ should satisfy $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0$ right?

(In case 1 is true, how do you call a flow with the properties of 2? How would it be mathematically different?)

Comment: $d\rho/dt$ would hold for (2) if $\mathbf u=0$ because it is not necessarily the case that $\nabla\rho=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality, the definition of incompressible fluid isn't what you listed. Physically speaking, incompressible means:

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial P} = 0 $$

or the change in density with pressure is zero. This in turn implies the speed of sound is infinite.

This also, technically, allows for changes in density with time if those changes are only due to temperature changes and not pressure changes, ie.

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T} \neq 0$$

Comment: Ugh, captial-p for pressure!? So weird. But +1 for giving a proper definition, and not using the more common statement of $\nabla\cdot\mathbf u=0$ (which is really a *result* of incompressibility).

Comment: @Kyle: and not a general result either, take e.g. the flow of a mixture with an heterogeneous density, then $\nabla\cdot u\not=0$. The zero-divergence condition should be noted as "solenoidal flow".